# What kind of array slice (?) is this?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm looking at some code and I see:

`y = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]`

For what it's worth, `type(X)=<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and `len(X)=150)`.

What is `y`? What kind of "slicing" is this? Does it remove or adjust certain members of X? Which and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to tell with 100% certainty what's going on from the code we can see, but this looks like a NumPy [advanced indexing operation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean).

When a NumPy array is indexed with an identically-shaped array of booleans, like so:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([[1, 2],
...                  [3, 4]])
>>> index_array = numpy.array([[True, False],
...                            [False, True]])
>>> x[index_array]
array([1, 4])
```

the result is an array of elements corresponding to each position of `x` where the index array had a `True` element. The elements appear in the result array in the same order they appear in the flattened version of `x`. The result is not a view; modifying it will not affect `x`. (This is a special case of more general behavior for when `x` and `index_array` are not identically-shaped, but the shapes are probably identical here, and the full behavior is really hard to understand.)

`&` is the [bitwise and operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). For booleans, this is pretty much the same as the regular and operator. For identically-shaped NumPy arrays of booleans:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([True, False, True])
>>> y = numpy.array([True, True, False])
>>> x & y
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

it goes through and `and`s corresponding elements to create an array of results. (Again, this is a special case of much more general behavior, but explaining the full generalities would quadruple the length of the post.)

Putting it together, we can guess that `class_member_mask` and `core_samples_mask` are boolean arrays representing which elements of `X` satisfy certain criteria.
`class_member_mask & core_samples_mask` then creates an array representing which elements of `X` fit *both* conditions, and `y = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]` selects all elements of `X` fitting both criteria.